# IntelliJ Idea can not resolve symbol f:viewAction

Tags: intellij-idea, jsf-2.2

My intelliJ idea is giving the  "can not resolve symbol f:viewAction" warning in red although the method in `action` attribute of `f:viewAction` is called.

It is also not giving auto complete for it. The auto complete works when i use `f:view` or `f:viewParam`. Also when i go to the `xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core` link, i can not find `<tag-name>viewAction</tag-name>` in that file so i am guessing i haven't included the right version may be?

My xhtml page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                template="components/defaultLayout.xhtml">

    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewAction action="#{indexBean.init}" />
    </f:metadata>
</ui:composition>
```

My Dependencies:

```
<!-- Mojarra api of jsf - needed for tomcat  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mojarra Implementation of jsf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
```

How can i include the correct library? and why is the action never the less called?